# Error implementing Elsa Workflow tutorial - Simple Document Approval WorkFlow

Tags: c#, .net, workflow

I've been doing the Elsa Workflow tutorial (.Net 6): Simple Document Approval. I've downloaded the elsa guide project and I'm following the tutorial instruction, but I have the following errors when I'm doing the DocumentApprovalWorkflow.cs class:

```
builder
                .WithDisplayName("Document Approval Workflow")
                .HttpEndpoint(activity => activity
                    .WithPath("/v1/documents")
                    .WithMethod(HttpMethod.Post.Method)
                    .WithReadContent())
                    .SetVariable("Document", context => context.GetInput<HttpRequestModel>()!.Body)
                    .SendEmail(activity => activity
                        .WithSender("workflow@acme.com")
                        .WithRecipient("josh@acme.com")
                        .WithSubject(context => $"Document received from {context.GetVariable<dynamic>("Document")!.Author.Name}")
                        .WithBody(context =>
                        {
                            var document = context.GetVariable<dynamic>("Document")!;
                            var author = document!.Author;
                            return $"Document from {author.Name} received for review.<br><a href=\"{context.GenerateSignalUrl("Approve")}\">Approve</a> or <a href=\"{context.GenerateSignalUrl("Reject")}\">Reject</a>";
                        }))
                    .WriteHttpResponse(
                        HttpStatusCode.OK,
                        "<h1>Request for Approval Sent</h1><p>Your document has been received and will be reviewed shortly.</p>",
                        "text/html")
                    .Then<Fork>(activity => activity.WithBranches("Approve", "Reject", "Remind"), fork =>
                    {
                        fork
                            .When("Approve")
                            .SignalReceived("Approve")
                            .SendEmail(activity => activity
                                .WithSender("workflow@acme.com")
                                .WithRecipient(context => context.GetVariable<dynamic>("Document")!.Author.Email)
                                .WithSubject(context => $"Document {context.GetVariable<dynamic>("Document")!.Id} Approved!")
                                .WithBody(context => $"Great job {context.GetVariable<dynamic>("Document")!.Author.Name}, that document is perfect."))
                            .ThenNamed("Join");

                        fork
                            .When("Reject")
                            .SignalReceived("Reject")
                            .SendEmail(activity => activity
                                .WithSender("workflow@acme.com")
                                .WithRecipient(context => context.GetVariable<dynamic>("Document")!.Author.Email)
                                .WithSubject(context => $"Document {context.GetVariable<dynamic>("Document")!.Id} Rejected")
                                .WithBody(context => $"Nice try {context.GetVariable<dynamic>("Document")!.Author.Name}, but that document needs work."))
                            .ThenNamed("Join");

                        fork
                            .When("Remind")
                            .Timer(Duration.FromSeconds(10)).WithName("Reminder")
                            .SendEmail(activity => activity
                                    .WithSender("workflow@acme.com")
                                    .WithRecipient("josh@acme.com")
                                    .WithSubject(context => $"{context.GetVariable<dynamic>("Document")!.Author.Name} is waiting for your review!")
                                    .WithBody(context =>
                                        $"Don't forget to review document {context.GetVariable<dynamic>("Document")!.Id}.<br><a href=\"{context.GenerateSignalUrl("Approve")}\">Approve</a> or <a href=\"{context.GenerateSignalUrl("Reject")}\">Reject</a>"))
                                .ThenNamed("Reminder");
                    })
                    .Add<Join>(join => join.WithMode(Join.JoinMode.WaitAny)).WithName("Join")
                    .WriteHttpResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "Thanks for the hard work!", "text/html");
```

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS1061  'IOutcomeBuilder' does not contain a definition for 'Timer' and no accessible extension method 'Timer' accepting a first argument of type 'IOutcomeBuilder' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)    DocumentManagement.Workflows

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS1929  'IActivityBuilder' does not contain a definition for 'WithBranches' and the best extension method overload 'ForkExtensions.WithBranches(ISetupActivity, params string[])' requires a receiver of type 'Elsa.Builders.ISetupActivity<Elsa.Activities.ControlFlow.Fork>'    DocumentManagement.Workflows

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS1061  'IActivityBuilder' does not contain a definition for 'SendEmail' and no accessible extension method 'SendEmail' accepting a first argument of type 'IActivityBuilder' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)  DocumentManagement.Workflows

Can someone help me?

I've updated the libraries to 2.10.2, and the issue is the same.